# Different Graph Bar with Python and Python in PowerBI

Tags: python, powerbi

It's my first time trying Python inside PowerBI, so I code in VS a GraphBar and I tried to put this same code inside PowerBI, but the result it's different and I don't know why. Please help me. Thks.

Code Python in PowerBI:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

nuevos_valores = {0: 'No disponible', 1: 'Empleado', 2: 'Trabaja Independiente', 3: 'Cesante', 5: 'Trabaja fuera de la ciudad', 9: 'Nómade'}


dataset.loc[dataset['FatherJobStatusCode'].isin(nuevos_valores.keys())
                , 'FatherJobStatusCode'] = dataset['FatherJobStatusCode'].map(nuevos_valores)

dataset.loc[dataset['MotherJobStatusCode'].isin(nuevos_valores.keys())
                ,'MotherJobStatusCode'] = dataset['MotherJobStatusCode'].map(nuevos_valores)


padres_counts = dataset['FatherJobStatusCode'].value_counts().sort_index()

madres_counts = dataset['MotherJobStatusCode'].value_counts().sort_index()


# Create a new DataFrame with the counts of both columns
counts_df = pd.DataFrame({'Padres': padres_counts, 'Madres': madres_counts})

ax = counts_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, color=['#FA05C7', '#0F26FA'], edgecolor='black')

# Set title and axis labels
ax.set_title('Conteo de Estatus laboral de los padres')
ax.set_xlabel('Categoría')
ax.set_ylabel('Conteo')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)

for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, label_type='edge', fontsize=8)

# Set the background color to 'None'
ax.set_facecolor('None')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Graph in Python

[image]

Graph Python inside PowerBI

[image]

The only differences it's that in VS code I connect directly with the SQL server and download the info and in PowerBI this automatically code this lines:

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(FatherJobStatusCode, MotherJobStatusCode)
dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()
```

My guess is that PowerBI eliminates more rows that expected, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is this `df.drop_duplicates()` that you need to work around.

Edit: It is the python *visual* that does this duplicate drop. Your loaded table in Power BI needs an index column (add in Power Query for example), and you need to use this index column in addition to your two other columns to "force" the `df.drop_duplicates()` to return your whole table.

See this relevant question I have answered previously: [Power BI Python visual doesn't plot all available datapoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74490261/power-bi-python-visual-doesnt-plot-all-available-datapoints/74490430#74490430)